# Importing enum values from a file

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum Tokens, which basically I use as codes for a logging system

```
public enum Tokens {
    UnknownCommand = 100,
    SoftwareVersion = 101
}
```

then I use a custom Logging that accepts a Token enum and a message:

```
Logger.LogError(Tokens.UnknownCommand, "SomeMessage")
```

This works well, however in a future my Tokens might have to change, so I was thinking that I could maybe import the token values from a Keys file.

However assigning new values to the Tokens doesn't seem to be a valid option.

```
Token.SoftwareVersion = 3;
```

Is there a way I can have an enum where the values can be imported from a file or changed?

Comment: `enum` is a compile time construct. If you want to create the runtime equivalent of `enum`, you need to use/store something that will immutably represent the state across multiple runs, like the actual string that is the meaning of the code, and store and work with those.

Comment: so what do you suggest I could use?

Comment: It is painful, but the only true flexible solution is storing the actual strings. If you can put some constraints on the Keys file, such as no Key will ever be deleted or re-ordered, then you could read the Keys file and create a Dictionary that maps Keys to their position in the file, and store that position, but you would still need to pass the string around in the code (e.g. for a given `LogError`, how do you know which Key it should use?)

Comment: It's _very_ unclear what your motivation is for doing this.  Please paint a much clearer picture of what future maintenance is supposed to look like.  Also is this an after-market feature (where one could drop in a new Keys file and get new functionality without rebuilding your code)?  What good is it to have new enums without having matching source code that references them?

Comment: Potentially build a dictionary of string, int instead and populate that from another source. You can then use that in place of the enum.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Enum Builder.

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        // Get the current application domain for the current thread.
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

        // Create a dynamic assembly in the current application domain,
        // and allow it to be executed and saved to disk.
        AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("TempAssembly");
        AssemblyBuilder ab = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        // Define a dynamic module in "TempAssembly" assembly. For a single-
        // module assembly, the module has the same name as the assembly.
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

        // Define a public enumeration with the name "Elevation" and an
        // underlying type of Integer.
        EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("YOUR_ENUM_NAME", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));


        // Read from file and then add to the enum members this way.
        // Define two members
        eb.DefineLiteral("UnknownCommand", 0);
        eb.DefineLiteral("SoftwareVersion", 1);

        // Create the type and save the assembly.
        Type finished = eb.CreateType();
        ab.Save(aName.Name + ".dll");


        // To retrieve Enum members use Enum.GetValues(YOUR_ENUM_NAME)
        foreach( object o in Enum.GetValues(YOUR_ENUM_NAME) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", finished, o, ((int) o));
        }
       //OR 

      Array values = Enum.GetValues ( typeof ( YOUR_ENUM_NAME ) );

        foreach (var val in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( String.Format ( "{0}: {1}",
                    Enum.GetName ( typeof ( YOUR_ENUM_NAME ), val ),
                    val ) );
        }
    }
```